# Javascript procedural image

Tags: javascript, image, creation

Is it possible to create in javascript(without connecting to server) image, that after creation can be placed on website? In example, I send only formula from server, and client creates image based on it which I can use as jpg/png/bmp background(and do repeating etc).

Comment: I`ve made you a demo. Probably this describes my idea better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. There is a [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial) element in HTML5. It can be used for 2d images and 3d animations etc.

[Here](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-tutorials-introduction/) is a set of tutorials about it.

Do you mean something like this:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var centerX = 70;
    var centerY = 70;
    var radius = 70;

    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(centerX, centerY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);

    context.fillStyle = "#8ED6FF";
    context.fill();
    context.lineWidth = 5;
    context.strokeStyle = "black";
    context.stroke();

var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
/*
   returns "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg...."
   it can be used wherever you want:
    -images 
    -style 
    -etc
*/
var b = document.getElementById("foo");
b.style.backgroundImage = "url(" + img + ")";
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shVbp/) and [with text](http://jsfiddle.net/shVbp/1/)

Comment: I was rather thinking about creating image, and than using it as background(so you can repeat it etc).

Answer (score 1):

If you want a cross browser solution look into [Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/).

Comment: I was rather thinking about creating image, and than using it as background as jpg/png(so you can repeat it etc).